# Linking extern variables in C

Tags: c, extern

In Unix, I have got three main files. One of them is a library and the other one is a program.

- `MyLib.c` and `MyLib.h` are the library.
- `main.c` is the program.

In `MyLib.h` I have a declaration (`extern int Variable;`). When I try to use `Variable` in `main.c` I cannot. Of course I have included `MyLib.h` in `MyLib.c` and in `main.c`, and I link them too. Anyway the variable is not recognized in `main.c`.

How do I get the variable available when I link the program?

Comment: Please post the source and the error. In particular, how have you managed to link when you cannot even build main.c ?

Comment: I had a main.c overthere, and I was just triying to understand how the compiler and linker work. But Chris Lutz's answer worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Variable` must be defined somewhere. I would declare it as a global variable in `MyLib.c`, and then only declare it as `extern` in `main.c`.

What is happening is that, for both `MyLib.c` and `main.c`, the compiler is being told that `Variable` exists and is an `int`, but that it's somewhere else (`extern`). Which is fine, but then it has to actually be somewhere else, and when your linker tries to link all the files together, it can't find `Variable` actually being anywhere, so it tells you that it doesn't exist.

Try this:

MyLib.c:

```
int Variable;
```

MyLib.h:

```
extern int Variable;
```

main.c:

```
#include "MyLib.h"

int main(void)
{
    Variable = 10;
    printf("%d\n", Variable);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just understood.

Comment: No problem. The numerous stages of compilation can be pretty confusing at first.